# What is the basicity order of peroxide, superoxide and hydroxide anions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

My teacher told me superoxide and  peroxide anion are more basic than hydroxide but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoxide)

> Given that the hydroperoxyl radical has a pKa of around 4.8

and and [pKa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water) of H2O is

> Acidity (pKa) 13.995[9][10][b]

Therefore, basicity of superoxide anion should be lesser than hydroxide as hydroperoxyl radical is more acidic than water.

For hydrogen peroxide I am not able to find pKa for both the hydrogen as it has two hydrogen so I don't know how to compare it, and I am not able to find the data of pKb of radical directly.

Comment: Water pKa is not the same thing as pKw.

Comment: Its given on wikepedia , i have provided the link you can check also

Comment: OK, I have seen the reasoning for both  14.0 and 15.7. Your Q is OK. See also https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Fundamentals/What_is_the_pKa_of_water%3F